# Why are principal K(A,n) fibrations induced by pullback

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, obstruction-theory

I am trying to classify such fibrations $p:E\to B$. I understand how to build a cochain representing the obstruction to building a section, and showing it is a cocycle, getting a cohomology class in $H^{n+1}(B;A)$. I want to show any other fibration with the same obstruction class is homotopic.

I know abstractly that the obstruction class corresponds to the homotopy class of some map $f:B\to K(A,n+1)$. If my original fibration was also induced by a map, I think I could show it must be in the same homotopy class, but I cannot convince myself that every fibration is actually induced, i.e., that the path fibration over $K(A,n+1)$ is `universal'.

Can someone give me a nudge in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a principal fibration with fiber $G$ to be universal, it suffices that its total space is (weakly) contractible.  In your situation, the path fibration $$G = K(A, n) \to PK(A,n+1) \to K(A,n+1)$$ has total space $PK(A,n+1)$, which is contractible.

Let $$G \to EG \to BG$$ be a principal $G$-fibration with contractible total space.  To show contractibility of the total space is a sufficient condition to induce all other principal bundles via pullback, suppose we are given another principal fibration $p: E \to B$ with fiber $G$.  Consider an "intermediate" principal $G$-fibration $$E \times_G EG \to E \times_G \{*\} \simeq B.$$  The fiber of this fibration is equivalent to $EG$, which is contractible.  Hence there exists a section $B \to E \times_G EG$.  The classifying map $B \to BG$ is obtained by the composition $$B \to E \times_G EG \to \{*\} \times_G EG \simeq BG.$$

Check that the pullback of $EG \to BG$ along this map gives a fibration isomorphic to the original fibration $E \to G$.

Comment: What does $E\times_G EG$ mean in this context? Does this use the H-space structure of $K(A,n)$?

Comment: Given $G$-spaces $X$ and $Y$, the *balanced product* $X \times_G Y$ is the quotient of $X \times Y$ by the diagonal $G$-action.  So yes, in some sense this uses the $H$-space (or rather, $A_\infty$) structure of $K(A, n)$.

Comment: I understand "principal fibration" to mean a fibration in which $\pi_1$ of the base acts trivially on $\pi_*$ of the fiber. Does this imply the fiber has an $A_\infty$ structure/how general is this characterization of being universal? Thank you for answering the question, by the way

Comment: Whether the fiber $G$ has a $A_\infty$ structure doesn't depend on the $\pi_1$-action; I only bring it up because that is what usually is needed to make sense of the delooping $BG$.  Depending on how strictly you interpret $K(A,n)$ and its action on the total space in your definition of a principal fibration, if your model gives you topological monoids, then the simple definition I gave of the balanced product works fine; if what you have instead is an $A_\infty$-space, then the balanced product should be constructed as a bar construction.  I don't think just being an $H$-space is enough.